# Perl Regex: Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE

Tags: regex, perl

I have this little Perl script that I use for extracting URLs from text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ( <STDIN> )
{
if ( /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;./~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/ )
{
print;
}
}
```

The Regex works fine when I search in Textwrangler, but when I run it through this script I get the following error:

```
$ cat file.txt | perl myscript.pl
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(http|ftp|https)://([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([ <-- HERE \w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;./ at myscript.pl line 5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `/` is the regex delimiters, you need to escape all the forward slashes present in your regex.

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;.\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?
```

I don't know what are you trying to achieve this `&amp` within character class. This `[&amp]` will match a single character from the given list whether it may be `&` or `a` or `m` or `p`, not the whole `&amp`

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted. You identified the problem (prematurely ended match operator) and how to fix it (escape the `/`).

Answer (score 5):

The `/` in the character class at the end needs to be escaped as well. You might consider using the `/x` modifier to make it more readable, and use different delimiters to avoid the "leaning toothpick". Also, the `\w` class
already includes the underscore, and `.` inside a character class always matches literally.

```
if (m{
        (http|ftp|https)://
        ( [\w\-]+ (?: (?:\.[\w\-]+)+ ) )
        (
          [\w\-.,@?^=%&amp;/~+#]*
          [\w\-@?^=%&amp;/~+#]
        )?
   }x
) {
    print;
}
```

By doing this, it also becomes fairly clear that the last two character classes are, well, not really character classes:

This: `/[&amp;]*/`
Will certainly match `&amp;` but also `a&m&p`, `ma`, `pa`, `&;`, etc., etc.

Comment: Yeah, this works great too. And is much more readable for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make that slightly more readable and debuggable, and, I hope that might shed some light on your problem.

```
while ( <STDIN> ) {
    print if m{
       ( http | ftp | https )://
       ( [\w\-_]+ (?: (?:\.[\w\-_]+)+ ) )
       ( 
            [\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;./~\+#]* 
            [\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#]
       )?
   }x;
```

On the other hand, I would have reached for [Regexp::Common::URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI) or [URI::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Find). Trying to fix this pattern doesn't seem to be the best use of anyone's time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check out the patterns you linked.